# Using variables in SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a database but taking a name and path from variables:

```
declare @Datapath nvarchar = serverproperty('InstanceDefaultDataPath');

declare @Database nvarchar = 'DatabaseName';

use master
go

if exists (select name from sys.databases where name = '@Database')
drop database [@Database]
go

create database [@Database] 
on primary ( 
  name = '@Database_Data'),
  filename = concat(@Datapath, '@Database_Data.mdf'),
  size = 200MB,
  maxsize = 20GB,
  filegrowth = 40MB 
)
collate Latin1_General_CI_AI

go
```

But I get the error on first line:

```
Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to nvarchar is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

And I am also getting an error on concat function.

I would like to use @Datapath and @Database on my query.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE 1**

```
declare @Datapath nvarchar(200) = cast(serverproperty('InstanceDefaultDataPath') as nvarchar(200));

declare @Database nvarchar(50) = 'DatabaseName';

use master
go

if exists (select name from sys.databases where name = '@Database')
drop database [@Database]
go

create database [@Database] 
on primary ( 
  name = '@Database',
  filename = concat(@Datapath, '@Database_Data.mdf'),
  size = 200MB,
  maxsize = 20GB,
  filegrowth = 40MB 
)
collate Latin1_General_CI_AI

go
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 mistakes in your T-SQL:

1. You don't specify the size of your `@Datapath` and `@Database` variables

Replace your

```
declare @YourVariable nvarchar = ...
```

By

```
declare @YourVariable nvarchar(<YourSize>) = ...
```

---

2. `serverproperty` returns a `sql_variant` so if you need a `nvarchar`, you can cast it.

Change

```
serverproperty('InstanceDefaultDataPath');
```

To

```
cast(serverproperty('InstanceDefaultDataPath') as nvarchar(200));
```

---

Here is the result:

```
declare @Datapath nvarchar(200) = cast(serverproperty('InstanceDefaultDataPath') as nvarchar(200));
declare @Database nvarchar(50) = 'DatabaseName';
```

Feel free to adjust the nvarchar size if needed.

Comment: But I still have a problem when using the variable in filename = concat(@Datapath, '@Database_Data.mdf'), or even with the convert option. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Then you will have to post the error. Is the script just a sample or is it the real query?

Comment: @Miguel - Do you want to name your database `@Database` or `DatabaseName`?

Comment: @Sébastian: I want its name to be DatabaseName. I just updated with the code I am trying now

Comment: @Sébastian: the code I am using, and that just posted, is the real query.

Comment: @Miguel - Then you need dynamic sql to create a database with a name coming from a variable. This is another issue that is not related to your original error and would be worth another post.

Comment: @Sábastian: thank you. I will create a new post for that question.